# Trying to project GeoPandas geodataframe geometry to new CRS is not working as expected

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, pyproj

I am working with GeoPandas and a Point GeoDataFrame. I have data points in WGS84 (EPSG=4326) that are located in New Zealand. I am trying to project them to a local UTM, but I cannot get the `geometry` of the GeoDataFrame to update with the new UTM coordinates.

Here is an example GeoDataFrame:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from pyproj import CRS
long = [172.083916, 172.086549, 172.093403]
lat = [-43.594391, -43.594758, -43.595249]
gdf_pt = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(long, lat))
gdf_pt.crs = 4326
display(gdf_pt)
print(gdf_pt.crs)
```

[image]

Failed Attempt #1 to project to [EPSG=2193](https://maps.omniscale.com/en/openstreetmap/epsg-2193)

```
myproject = gdf_pt.copy()
myproject.crs = 2193
print(myproject.crs)
display(myproject)
```

[image]

Failed Attempt #2

```
myproject['geometry'] = myproject['geometry'].to_crs(epsg=2193)
display(myproject)
```

[image]

I also tried it with [EPSG=32759](https://maps.omniscale.com/en/openstreetmap/epsg-32759), another suitable NZ UTM... same issue

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting the `crs` attribute to the new CRS (2193), you are *assigning* a CRS definition (you are setting the metadata), however the coordinates remain unchanged so the CRS is now incorrect (you have not changed the data to match the assigned CRS). For more info, see the [Managing Projections: Reprojecting](https://geopandas.org/projections.html#re-projecting) docs.

You need to *reproject* the coordinates using the [`GeoDataFrame.to_crs`](https://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs) method.

```
myproject = gdf_pt.to_crs(2193)
print(myproject)
print(myproject.crs)
```

Output:

```
                          geometry
0  POINT (1526055.119 5172768.014)
1  POINT (1526268.100 5172729.595)
2  POINT (1526821.938 5172681.124)
epsg:2193
```

Comment: That's so obvious and makes sense, thanks. I don't understand why `myproject['geometry'] = myproject['geometry'].to_crs(epsg=2193)` doesn't work?